# Changing the color of the legend linetype in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a graph line by gender (color) and age (linetype). The resulting graph presents a legend with two colors on a solid line for gender  and two **black** line types for age. I would like to control the color of the linetypes (say green instead of black).

Any idea?

```
df = expand_grid(
  year = c(2010, 2020),
  gender = c('male', 'female'),
  age = c('young', 'old')) %>% 
  mutate(y = 1:8)

ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y = y, color = gender, linetype = age)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to make use of the `override.aes` argument of `guide_legend`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y = y, color = gender, linetype = age)) + 
  geom_line() +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = "green")))
```

[image]